# SSOM - How to set a custom property value when adding web part programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, web-part, ssom

I want to set a custom property value when add web part programmatically.

This is my code for add web part in page:

```
            using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = oWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager(newPage.Url, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
            {
                try
                {
                    string wPartURL = oWeb.Site.Url + "/_catalogs/wp/ClientViewProjects.webpart";
                    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(oWeb.GetFileAsString(wPartURL)));

                    string err = null;
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart)manager.ImportWebPart(reader, out err);
                    wp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
                    manager.AddWebPart(wp, "Header", 0); //See the description below for how to determine Zone
                    manager.SaveChanges(wp);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LOG_STRING += string.Format("В сайт с URL:{0}{1} {2}", oWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, ex.ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
                }
                finally
                {
                    manager.Web.Dispose();
                }

                newPage.CheckIn("Checked in by Code");
                newPage.ListItem.File.Publish("Publishing major version");
            }
```

Comment: "wp.CustomPropertName = value" isn't working?

Comment: no such property

Comment: Please add the code where you have create custom property

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer:**

```
PropertyInfo[] pinProperties = wp.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
     foreach (PropertyInfo pinProperty in pinProperties)
     {
     if (pinProperty.Name == "City")
     {
            pinProperty.SetValue(wp, "propValue", null);
     }
     if (pinProperty.Name == "Status")
     {
           pinProperty.SetValue(wp, "propValue", null);
     }
}
```